# Multiple UV for unwrapped object

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, uv-image-editor

Creating a plan of a room with 2 types of wallpaper.

I am using a UV map for each wallpaper.

I managed to get the UV map for wallpaper 1 (called StripeWallpaperLivingRoom) to successfully apply to the first set of walls. At this time, during development, I had unwrapped the other walls with this map but was going to sort that out when applying the second wallpaper (PlumWallpaperLivingRoom) to these walls.

I am attempting that now and unwrapped these walls so that they appeared default blank. However, although I have the unwrap mesh set up correctly aligned for my second wallpaper, it is not reflecting on the actual wall render.

The image for the correctly rendering StripeWallpaperLivingRoom is called 20-944_3.jpg and PlumWallpaperLivingRoom is called graham-brown-wallpaper-20-200-76_1000.jpg.

In Materials, these are called StriaStripe and StriaPlum respectively.

The Texture property does seem to only reflect the 20-944_3.jpg so maybe I should have done something here?? Also, even though I did unwrap to remove from the original UV map, the maps for the original 3 walls have appeared randomly on the original StripeWallpaperLivingRoom  and I think this is overriding my new PlumWallpaperLivingRoom map.

I am still a NOOB so if you can see where my misunderstanding is, please can you explain in detail. Thanks.

I am attaching screen prints to relate this info to.

[image: Trying to apply PlumWallpaperLivingRoom to facing walls. UVMap set up. Original mistaken effort still on wall]

[image: Same after attempting to remove original mistake so showing a random image based on a map against other image]

[image: Material for StriaStripe]

[image: Texture]

[image: New pic showing StriaPlum now assigned to wall but it needs to be UV mapped to fit correctly. Not sure what to do next]

Comment: give each part of your objects its own material, and in each material use a different Input > UVMap node, but I'm not sure to have correctly understood your question  ;)

Comment: You don't need two UV maps, but two different materials and apply them to whatever faces you need them.  And please use the tools from this site to show your images as part of the question and not as a list of links.

Answer (score 1):

You have two materials for one object: StriaStripe and StriaPlum. StriaStripe is on top and was put on the object first, and therefor the object is shown with that material.

If you delete StriaStripe in the Material Properties tab, the object will only have StriaPlum as a material, and then you can see it on your object.

But maybe you don't want to delete it.

In that case you have to select StriaPlum in the Material Properties (click it and it will have a gray bar over it). Then go into Edit Mode with <kbd>Tab</kbd>  and press <kbd>A</kbd>  to select all the faces of your object. Then click Assign (under the material list in the Material Properties tab), and the faces will get the selected material. Now the object is shown with the other material.

So with the Assign button you can give different materials to different faces, and one object can also have a material on part of the faces, and another material on other faces.

Comment: I got this working (a bit unsure as to the chain of events that got there but I did). However, I had to delete and recreate one of the faces and this meant UV unwrapping this face. This time I have been having issues in that I cannot find the unwrapped face island in UV Editor. There does not appear to be any way of zooming into this on the editor. I seem to have to attempt panning backwards and forwards but I have been unable to find it. Any ideas?

Comment: Great! : )   (I hope the answer and the comments helped you though; i think they did explain what was going on.) And try pressing the "." key on the numpad when you have the face selected, while you are in the UV Editor window. This works for most windows to find a selected thing.

Comment: Sorry, yes the advice did help. Should have said that.

Comment: Sorry, yes the advice did help. Should have said that.It however got weirder for the one wall (single face with a doorway cut into it) that I am working on. I've used Project from View to try and get some semblance of the 8 vertices shape and this is showing in the UV editor as expected. However, it needs to be scaled up with the wallpaper image below. There appears to be something limiting scaling so I cannot expand the Island to the correct size. All moving of Island elements is constrained to this size. I clicked UV Sync Selection. this shows it linked to the other completed islands

Comment: Usually it is best to make a new question for a new problem. In any case, it is hard to determine you problem form description alone. You might want to consider sharing you .blend file by uploading it here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ If you do decide to share the file, don't forget to go (in Blender) to File > Eternal Data, and check the box next to "Automatically Pack Into .blend". Then the textures will be in the file and otherwise other people won't be able to see them in your scene.